# Does Density Property assure the continuity of a Non-Contractive Function?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

I want to be sure about a detail:

We know that, any contractive function is continuous. Reformulated in other words, any function that does not increase distance is continuous.

But, suppose we are in $\mathbb{R}$, and we have a distance increasing function $f$ on a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Does the **density** property of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ guarantee the continuity of this function $f$? ie. Will the image of $A$ by $f$ still be dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \frac12 x$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 2x$ for $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$. $f$ is contractive on the dense set $\mathbb{Q}$ but not on $\mathbb{R}$ and nowhere continuous except at $x=0$.

Comment: you saying there exists non continuous functions which are contracting too, right?

Comment: @freehumorist No, this function is not contracting and it's not continuous.

Comment: so how is this an answer to my question? I thought I asked that, when we have a distance-increasing function over a dense set, the continuity would be preserved in the image set too...

Comment: @freehumorist we also have here a distance increasing function on the dense irrationals and no continuity. So it does answer that too. BTW Distance increasingness does not imply continuity, decreasingness does (but on the whole domain).

Comment: Ok I got your answer. I think I should add another criteria: I want the function to be linear and monotone. Your example amazed me, now that I get; though it is not the answer I wanted.

Comment: @freehumorist linear functions will always be continuous on the reals. That’s not very interesting nor hard.

Comment: Ok. I know what you just said. It was a part of thoughts I had over the answer for an exercise. I had to be sure